# how can i fix the 'syntax error' in python using jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

hi tried to fix the error but i could not and i dont know where im going wrong can anyone please help . below is my code

my previous error was indentation error

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
import sklearn as s 
import matplotlib 
import tensorflow as tf 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from IPython.display import display 
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/patel/Desktop/tap.csv")
from IPython.display import display
X_all = df.drop(['FTR'],1)
y_all = df['FTR']

# Standardising the data.
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

#Center to the mean and component wise scale to unit variance.
cols = [['FTHG','FTAG','HTHG','HTAG']]
for col in cols:
    X_all[col] = scale(X_all[col])
X_all.HM1 = X_all.HM1.astype('str')
X_all.HM2 = X_all.HM2.astype('str')
X_all.HM3 = X_all.HM3.astype('str')
X_all.AM1 = X_all.AM1.astype('str')
X_all.AM2 = X_all.AM2.astype('str')
X_all.AM3 = X_all.AM3.astype('str')
def preprocess_features(X):
    output = pd.DataFrame(index = X.index)
    for col, col_df in X.iteritems():
             if col_df.dtype == object:
                col_df = pd.get_dummies(col_df, prefix = col)
    output = output.join(col_df)
    return output
X_all = preprocess_features(X_all)
print "Processed feature columns ({} total features):\n{}".format(len(X_all.columns), list(X_all.columns))
print "\nFeature values:"
display (X_all)
```

File "", line 39
    print "Processed feature columns ({} total features):\n{}".format(len(X_all.columns), list(X_all.columns))
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Hi @Shuvojit im using the latest version of python i.e 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python 3, then the parentheses in `print` function are missing. The following code should work.

```
print("Processed feature columns ({} total features):\n{}".format(len(X_all.columns), list(X_all.columns)))
```

Comment: BUt now i had dataframe error after what i fixed i dont know why ?